# How to create subsequences from a set of ordered integers given the specified constraints.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations, combinations

Given, for example, the following set of integers $\{1,2,3,4\}$, how can you compute the number of all possible sequence scenarios, where a scenario consists of a number of sequences, as following ones^

scenario 1: $(1,2,3,4)$
scenario 2: $(1,4)(2,4)(3,4)$
scenario 3: $(1,4)(2,3,4)$
scenario 4: $(1,2,4)(3,4)$
scenario 5: $(1,3,4)(2,4)$

In general, given a set of $n$ integers, how many sequence scenarios you can create if a scenario is defined as a set of sequences such that:

- all integers from 1 to n-1 are used within a scenario exactly once.
- each sequence has n as the last integer
- in each sequence, integers are ordered with increasing ordering
- the ordering of the sequences is not relevant, it is important that no scenario is the same to any other

What would be a mathematical equation for computing a number of those scenarios? Or at least what could be an algorithm for their computing?

Comment: You say that only $n$ (4 is your example) may be repeated, but in the last two scenarios, 3 is also repeated.

Comment: Does [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationAscent.html) answer your last scenario?

Comment: Sorry, that is a mistake. I will edit it.

Comment: @SabyasachiBasu Not quite, that one was a mistake, I corrected it.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused about what exactly you mean by your scenarios, and it would be helpful (for me) if you mapped the 3 scenarios to the 5 preceding them.

Comment: A scenario is a set of sequences such that:
- all integers from 1 to n-1 are used within sequences exactly once.
- each sequence has n as the last integer
- in each sequence, integers are ordered with increasing ordering
- the ordering of the sequences is not relevant, it is important that no scenario is the same to any other.
Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), given in [OEIS A000110](http://oeis.org/A000110).  You are asking for the number of ways to partition $n-1$ labeled items into disjoint subsets.  You then sort the subsets and append $n$ to each to get one of your scenarios.  The sequence begins $$1, 2, 5, 15, 52, 203, 877, 4140, 21147, 115975, 678570$$
where the $5$ represents $B_3$ because you partition $\{1,2,3\}$ and there are $5$ ways to do it as you found.  The recurrence for them is 
$$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}B_k$$

Comment: You are definitely right. Do you know any algorithm which is able to generate those disjoint subsets?

Comment: The recurrence suggests one.  Given the set of $n+1$, for each $k$ in the range $0$ to $n$ the first set has $1$ and $n-k$ out of the other $n$ items.  Choose each combination of $k$, partition those, and add the set of all the rest.  This is taken from the Wikipedia article where I found the recurrence.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will be able to do it now! Thanks a lot!